# Output and format a text file to html using node.js

Tags: node.js

I am looking to output the contents of a text file to a webpage using node.js. I have managed to get the text from the file and have been able to use it together with some basic HTML to render a page but the text has lost all its formatting and is rendered as one long string:

i.e. the contact.txt file has the following in it:

```
   Peter
   Robert
   Bob
```

but when I use `fs.readFile` I get the following on my page:

```
  Peter Robert Bob
```

Does anyone know how to preserve the line breaks in the original text file? The code I am using follows

```
  fs.readFile('contact.txt', (error, txtString) => {
            if(error) throw err; 
            console.log(txtString.toString());
            res.write(

  '<div id="content">'+ txtString.toString()
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR: Use `<pre>` in  HTML or `.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')` in Node.js

- ### [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) in HTML keeps ALL formatting
- ### [`.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) in Node.js ONLY fixes newlines

---

`fs.readFile` returns the following correctly:

```
   Peter
   Robert
   Bob
```

But, look at this:

```html
<div>
   Peter
   Robert
   Bob
</div>
```

Notice that the output is `Peter Robert Bob`.

To fix this, you have a few options. The first is `<pre>` tags:

```html
<div><pre>
   Peter
   Robert
   Bob
</pre></div>
```

Using this solution, your code would be:

```js
  fs.readFile('contact.txt', (error, txtString) => {
            if(error) throw err; 
            console.log(txtString.toString());
            res.write(

  '<div id="content"><pre>'+ txtString.toString()+'</pre>'
  );
```

The next would be replacing newlines with `<br />` (the HTML newline) on the server. With this approach, your code would look like:

```js
  fs.readFile('contact.txt', (error, txtString) => {
            if(error) throw err; 
            console.log(txtString.toString());
            res.write(

  '<div id="content"><pre>'+ txtString.toString().replace(/\n/g, '<br />')+'</pre>'
  );
```

With that, the response looks like:

```html
<div>       Peter<br />       Robert<br />       Bob<br />    </div>
```